# Initializing an object only one time in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to show a ticker message which is coded in a separate class and i am using the class in below way

below code shows a ticker message in iphone simulator on current view when i run in xcode

```
#import "CLTickerView.h" //imported ticker message class

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, -3, 80, 40)];

   ticker.marqueeStr = @"OLD Ticker msg goes here";

   ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
   [self.view addSubview:ticker];

}
```

i want to change the ticker message and position by a button and i am using below code

```
- (IBAction)changeTitleAndPosition:(id)sender {
{
   CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 50)]; //i want to change the position here

   ticker.marqueeStr = @"NEW Ticker msg goes here"; //i want to change msg here

   ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
   [self.view addSubview:ticker];

}
```

but when i click the button, it creates duplicate ticker message every time, is it possible that we can only change message and position?

I know that when i click the button it creates new object every time and shows duplicate message. But i don't know how i can initialize the object one time in viewDidLoad and change title and position of the msg from any button or action.

Please suggest me the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:  as long as you have a reference to the ticker and an active instance, you can change it's properties without having to create a new instance.  Declare CLTickerView as a property of the calling class.